# Visualizar perguntas por tags favoritas

Tags: debate, novo-recurso, perguntas, tags

Não seria interessante quando entrássemos no [SOPT](http://pt.stackoverflow.com) ter uma aba com as perguntas feitas que incluíssem somente as nossas tags favoritas?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se assim fosse poderíamos ver só as perguntas as quais temos "capacidade" de resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Existe uma opção de selecionar perguntas de determinadas tags.Em baixo do boletim da comunidade click em editar > assinaturas de tags avançadas.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nessa tela é possivel fazer o filtro de tags e em quais sites
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não fazia a menor ideia, obrigado pelo esclarecimento. Mas para ver com esse filtro não estou a ver o SOPT, estou a ver no [Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com/filters/80692/sopt-filter)  certo?

Comment: Acho que só é possível acessar o filtro pelo SE mesmo pois até a tela de seleção é em inglês.

Comment: Isso é um bocado chato visto que a ideia é ser tudo em português e para quem não percebe nada de inglês fica complicado. Ai a minha pergunta mantém-se.